# script for creating bootable usb

Tags: grub2, usb, parted

I have been using the following bash script on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS to create a bootable USB disk for an embedded system, which worked fine:

```
# Partition disk.
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/umount /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdc2
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/parted -s -- /dev/sdc mklabel msdos
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/parted -s -- /dev/sdc mkpart primary 2048s 5244928s
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/parted -s -- /dev/sdc set 1 boot on
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/parted -s -- /dev/sdc mkpart primary 5246976s -977920s
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/parted -s -- /dev/sdc quit
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/partprobe /dev/sdc
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/umount /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdc2
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/mkfs.ext4 -L rootfs /dev/sdc1
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/mkfs.ext4 -L var /dev/sdc2
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/partprobe /dev/sdc
/bin/sync

# Copy filesystem.
/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc1
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/cp -a ${ROOTFS_DIR}/. ${ROOTFS_MOUNTPOINT}
/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc2
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/cp -a ${VAR_DIR}/. ${VAR_MOUNTPOINT}
/bin/sync

# Upload bootloader.
/usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc1
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/grub-install --no-floppy --directory=${ROOTFS_MOUNTPOINT}/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc --locale-directory=${ROOTFS_MOUNTPOINT}/usr/share/locale --boot-directory=${ROOTFS_MOUNTPOINT}/boot /dev/sdc
/bin/sync
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/eject /dev/sdc
```

The output of `fdisk` for the generated USB disk is:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 14.9 GiB, 16022241280 bytes, 31293440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x22953b4d

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *       2048  5244928  5242881  2.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2       5246976 30315520 25068545   12G 83 Linux
```

Recently, I switched to Ubuntu 18.04, but now, `grub` loads the linux kernel and initramfs, though afterwards booting fails with the following output, and it drops to emergency shell:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

In the emergency shell, `blkid` command shows the partitions as expected, which matches the UUIDs in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="5556accb-3244-47d0-8042-aaad74dd3950" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="22953b4d-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="var" UUID="6ee3b764-77dB-481d-9564-fbfabb590933" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="22953b4d-02"
```

Since I have already experienced some other problems in Ubuntu 18.04, such as different behavior from `losetup`, different output format for `fdisk`, etc. should I provide further command options for `mkfs.ext4` or `grub-install` commands in the script? `grub-install` command is from Ubuntu with version `2.02-2ubuntu8.13`, but its options use directories from the embedded filesystem which has grub `2.02.beta2-4`, so, can there be some inconsistencies due to this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out `mkfs.ext4` was the reason, since the command is newer on Ubuntu 18.04 than the `mount`er on the embedded system, causing the following error during boot:

```
EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p2): couldn't mount RDWR because of unsupported optional features (400)
```

Based on [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287159/linux-couldnt-mount-rdwr-because-of-unsupported-optional-features-400) and [this information](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Metadata_Checksums), I disabled the `metadata_csum` feature with the following option while creating the filesystem, and the system booted normally:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/mkfs.ext4 -O ^metadata_csum -L 'rootfs' /dev/sdc1
```